# Book about a guy playing a cursed video game that took place in his town

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

There was a book I read back in middle school (I'm 23 now) that I can't remember the name of and I've been trying to track it down for years.

From what I can remember (and my memory is not that good), it was about a guy playing a video game that took place in his town. It had him committing crimes but in the end the game turns on him and he watches the character in the computer screen go towards his house to kill him.

That's all I really remember. I think the book was fairly old when I read it; it looked like an old book and for a long time I even thought it was a Christopher Pike book, but I haven't been able to find it through him.

If anyone knows this book please let me know because I've been going crazy trying to find it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Roughly how old was the main character? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: I think he was a young kid. Maybe a pre teen or teenage. As for the cover i dont remember

Answer (score 4):

*End Game* by Damien Graves

Description from [goodreads.com](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/11243554-end-game):

> Simon prefers computer games to reality, but a shockingly real turn of
> events might mean "Game Over"--forever. This story and two additional
> contributions equal three more ways to define the word "fear."

It has been identified on similar sounding [reddit TOMT](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/wv1b9k/tomtbook2000s_childrens_anthology_series/) search.

Comment: Pretty nice summary at https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/21560767?book_show_action=true

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats it! I made this account just to find this book so thank you lol you all are amazing!